# How to get data out of a Node.js http get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, request

I'm trying to get my function to return the http get request, however, whatever I do it seems to get lost in the ?scope?. I'm quit new to Node.js so any help would be appreciated

```
function getData(){
  var http = require('http');
  var str = '';

  var options = {
        host: 'www.random.org',
        path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
  };

  callback = function(response) {

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
              str += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
              console.log(str);
        });

        //return str;
  }

  var req = http.request(options, callback).end();

  // These just return undefined and empty
  console.log(req.data);
  console.log(str);
}
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Of course your logs return `undefined` : you log before the request is done. The problem isn't scope but *asynchronicity*.

`http.request` is asynchronous, that's why it takes a callback as parameter. Do what you have to do in the callback (the one you pass to `response.end`):

```
callback = function(response) {

  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(req.data);
    console.log(str);
    // your code here if you want to use the results !
  });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: I would recommend pushing the chunks into an array and then use join('') in the end. That will avoid issues if there is lots of data

Comment: How do I get the HTTP response code of the response (200 or 404 etc.)? Is there any documentation about the keyword 'on' (response.on), 'data' and 'end'? Are these keywords? There seems to be nothing here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Comment: @TylerDurden `statusCode` is a property of the response object. I couldn't find proper documentation for the `ServerResponse` object either, just examples in the docs for the `get` and `request` methods.

Comment: But this makes the code messy! Why is javascript designed like this?

Comment: @Daniel There are now facilities to handle the asynchronous event model: Promises and async/await.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Would using a promise library (ie Axios) correctly concatenate the returned data then? So can I assume the .then with return all the data and the .catch will return a complete error  if any)?

Answer (score 34):

Simple Working Example of Http request using node.

```
const http = require('https')

httprequest().then((data) => {
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
    return response;
});
function httprequest() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
            path: '/todos',
            port: 443,
            method: 'GET'
        };
        const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
          if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
                return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
            }
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                try {
                    body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
                } catch(e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject(e.message);
        });
        // send the request
       req.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank for share!! This was the unique sample with return data without use console.log.

Comment: Seconded re @AltieresdeMatos's comment. This is a good, complete, *practical* example, that actually answers the original question as stated. This should be the accepted answer (in 2021) I reckon. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 22):

Shorter example using http.get:

```
require('http').get('http://httpbin.org/ip', (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Comment: This example is about as short as you can get and still run.  This assumes a good url and small response.  I prefer the http examples that chunk the data response, use the response `end` event, and use the request `errror` event.

Comment: This answer is out of context given the question asked. Beside that, you are not explicitly listening for the `error event ` which will be triggered if the connection is lost while the request is in-progress or if any other issues occur during transmission.

Comment: Warning: I think 'data' can give partial updates, the 'response' event is more practical.

Answer (score 12):

from learnyounode:

```
var http = require('http')  

http.get(options, function (response) {  
  response.setEncoding('utf8')  
  response.on('data', console.log)  
  response.on('error', console.error)  
})
```

'options' is the host/path variable

Comment: thanks, been looking all over for a simple example and every one I found threw half a dozen new concepts at me. This just laid out how the http.get()  works nice and simple. Excellent!

Comment: Warning: I think 'data' can give partial updates, the 'response' event is more practical

Answer (score 9):

from learnyounode:

```
var http = require('http')
var bl = require('bl')

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
    response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            return console.error(err)
        data = data.toString()
        console.log(data)
    }))
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's too late to answer this question but I faced the same problem recently my use case was to call the paginated JSON API and get all the data from each pagination and append it to a single array.

```
const https = require('https');
const apiUrl = "https://example.com/api/movies/search/?Title=";
let finaldata = [];
let someCallBack = function(data){
  finaldata.push(...data);
  console.log(finaldata);
};
const getData = function (substr, pageNo=1, someCallBack) {

  let actualUrl = apiUrl + `${substr}&page=${pageNo}`;
  let mydata = []
  https.get(actualUrl, (resp) => {
    let data = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    resp.on('end', async () => {
        if (JSON.parse(data).total_pages!==null){
          pageNo+=1;
          somCallBack(JSON.parse(data).data);
          await getData(substr, pageNo, someCallBack);
        }
    });
  }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  });
}

getData("spiderman", pageNo=1, someCallBack);
```

Like @ackuser mentioned we can use other module but In my use case I had to use the node `https`. Hoping this will help others.

Comment: Thanks dude, I ran into the same situation like you, it sucks we can only use the `https` for issuing https request.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution, although for sure you can use a lot of modules that give you the object as a promise or similar. Anyway, you were missing another callback

```
function getData(callbackData){
  var http = require('http');
  var str = '';

  var options = {
        host: 'www.random.org',
        path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
  };

  callback = function(response) {

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
              str += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
              console.log(str);
          callbackData(str);
        });

        //return str;
  }

  var req = http.request(options, callback).end();

  // These just return undefined and empty
  console.log(req.data);
  console.log(str);
}
```

somewhere else

```
getData(function(data){
// YOUR CODE HERE!!!
})
```

Comment: this seems not to work as callbackData() is not defined as a function?

Answer (score 0):

use async + await + Promise and make the result a return value instead of callback.

```js
const f = async (s) =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = "";
        const req = http.request(
            {
                hostname: "127.0.0.1",
                port,
                path: "/",
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Content-Length": s.length,
                },
            },
            (res) => {
                res.on("data", (d) => {
                    data += d.toString();
                });
                res.on("end", () => {
                    resolve(data);
                });
            }
        );
        req.write(s);
        req.end();
    });
```

then `await f("data")`