# Is it possible to log HTTP request client side with javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, post, get

Is it possible to log HTTP request client side with javascript? For instance going to some website-> opening the chrome console-> enter some javascript and console.log `GET` and `POST` URL's. Similar as the chrome network tab does. I have Googled but couldn't find anything that addresses this problem. Is this only possible server side?

Comment: You already checked the suggested answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539391/how-to-get-data-out-of-a-node-js-http-get-request or doesn't that fit your requirements?

Comment: @matthias_h Thats not me what are you talking about?

Comment: Its an entirely different thing also...are you drunk:)

Comment: Sorry, that's a misunderstanding. I just thought the proposed answer on link above would be of help to solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the request for the current page, no, there's not much you can do client-side. You can get some information on AJAX requests from the XMLHttpRequest object, but not as thorough as the browser's developer tools.