# How to pipe a HTTPS get response into an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, https, get

I transformed my code so that instead of requiring an extra node_modules, I could just use some HTTPS GET requests, the problem is that when I try to pipe `/releases/` which is basically a raw JSON file, my code requires it back and issues occur like `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`, because for some reason, when I console.log() the so called JSON array, the end isn't completed with ] or }. So I try to pipe the response into an array, but now I get an error: `dest.on isn't a function`,

Code:

```
    https.get({hostname: `api.github.com`, path: `/repos/${username}/${reponame}/releases`, headers: {'User-Agent': 'a user agent'}}, async (response) => {
        var file = new Array()
        response.pipe(file)
        response.on('end', async function() { //issue occurs at response.pipe ???
        var releases = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./releases.json', 'utf8'))
        console.log(releases)
```

The JSON file that I access from Github looks like: https://api.github.com/repos/davidmerfield/randomColor/releases (random repository)

But, my file (releases.json) looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/72sXLxM6)

Edit: I did extensive testing. I used the same JSON file my pkg outputted, read it with fs and so on, and everything seems fine. So the issue is most likely with https / response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to pipe the HTTP request into an object, instead of piping it into a file. Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539391/how-to-get-data-out-of-a-node-js-http-get-request). I did that and turned the string into a JSON array.

```js
https.get({hostname: `api.github.com`, path: `/repos/${username}/${reponame}/releases`, headers: {'User-Agent': 'agent'}}, async response => {
        var str = ''
        response.on('data', (data) => {
            str += data
        })
        response.on('end', async function() {
        var releases = JSON.parse(str)
//and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `require` JSON files. So, if you need this file, you can do something like:

```
const releases = require('./releases.json');
```

You do not need to read it with fs, unless you really want to.

Comment: When I call the file by doing that, it says the file has a SyntaxError even though when I open the file, it's completely fine. It might be something to do with https piping it to the JSON file as completely one line of JSON

Comment: You are going to have to show us the JSON for us to help with that. It sounds like it is a malformed JSON string.

Comment: Here's a pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/72sXLxM6, and i editted my post with that, it's one looong line of JSON. My other repository only has 4 releases, so it's way shorter.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: dest.on is not a function

This error will be thrown if you try to pipe to non-Writable Stream object. [Check here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)

Which in this case Array is not a Writable Stream. You can create a writable stream using `fs.createWriteStream()` and pipe the response to it.

```js
https.get(
  { hostname: `api.github.com`, path: `/repos/${username}/${reponame}/releases`, headers: { "User-Agent": "a user agent" } },
  async response => {
    const writableStreamFile = fs.createWriteStream("./releases.json");
    response.pipe(writableStreamFile);
    response.on("end", async function() {
      var releases = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./releases.json", "utf8"));
      console.log(releases);
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Results in a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`, and that occurs at the `JSON.parse` code

Comment: Not very sure, but might be the issue with async execution of javascript, try reading the file on `close` instead of `end`. IO operation tends to take time.

Comment: @RajeshSharma you can't call pipe from response since it is not readableStream, he needs to add {responseType: 'stream'} in the get request.