# How to return the response from a Nodejs' HTTPS GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am still learning node.js, so please be kind.

I am struggling to get my head around some of the basics without having a book open.

I have written a function to go out and get some JSON from a URL. This works but how do I return the data from the function, then pick bits out. here is my code. SerialNumber is one of the JSON elements being returned.

```js
const https = require('https');

function authenticate( uuid , cdcloc ) {
    let url = cdcloc + "/api.php?uuid=" + uuid + '&auth';
    https.get(url,(res) => {
        let body = "";
        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
            try {
                let cdcResponse = JSON.parse(body);
                // do something with JSON
                return cdcResponse[0];
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
            };
        });
    }).on("error", (error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
    });
}
const connection = authenticate( 'DATATOBEPASSED' , 'https://URLHERE');
console.log(connection.SerialNumber);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data out of a Node.js http get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539391/how-to-get-data-out-of-a-node-js-http-get-request)

Comment: so cdcResponse[0] does have a value ? you could let my_var = " in the beginnin of the function and overwrite it with cdcResponse[0] than you could return my_var from the function

Answer (score 5):

**node-style callbacks**

The answer from O.Jones is correct but it goes against Node's convention of [error-first callbacks](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/). I think it is also a mistake to reach for `https.get` every single time you need to make a request. It is a low-level function and because it asks you to connect so many bits and pieces, it is likely you will make easily-avoidable mistakes.

We can write a generic `getString` function that wraps `https.get` -

```js
const https = require('https')

function getString(url, options, callback)
{ https
    .get(url, options, res => {
      let s = "";
      res.on("data", d => s += d)
      res.on("end", _ => callback(null, s) // error-first callback
    })
    .on("error", e => callback(e))         // error-first callback
}
```

Now that we have a generic function to fetch a string, we don't need to write `res.on("data, ...)` and `res.on("end", ...)` in every function that makes a request. But don't stop here. You will often want to `JSON.parse` the result -

```js
function getJSON(url, options, callback)
{ getString(url, options, function(err, data)
  { if (err) callback(err)                         // getString error
    else try { callback(null, JSON.parse(data) }   // JSON.parse success
    catch (e) { callback(e) }                      // JSON.parse error
  }
}
```

Now we can write `authenticate` without having touch the bare `https.get` or worrying about parsing JSON each time -

```js
function authenticate(uuid, cdcloc, callback)             // callback
{ const url = cdcloc + "/api.php?uuid=" + uuid + '&auth'
  getJSON(url, {}, function(err, json)
  { if (err)
      callback(err)                                       // getJSON error
    else if (json.length == 0)
      callback(Error("empty response"))                   // empty response error
    else
      callback(null, json[0])                             // success
  }
}
```

**promises**

But all of this is pretty painful still, isn't it? Enter Promises. Node-style callbacks were designed at a time when we didn't have access to async control flow primitives. We've come a long way since then. To see how promises work, we will re-implement the functions above, but this time without the need to pass callback and error-check everywhere -

```js
const https = require('https')

function getString(url, options)           // no callback
{ return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  // return Promise
  { https
      .get(url, options, res => {
        let s = "";
        res.on("data", d => s += d)
        res.on("end", _ => resolve(s))     // success, resolve
      })
      .on("error", e => reject(e))         // failure, reject
  }
}
```

We immediately see the benefits of our new implementation when we rewrite `getJSON` -

```js
function getJSON(url, options = {})   // no callback
{ return getString(url, options)      // return promise
    .then(s => JSON.parse(s))         // errors auto bubble up
}
```

And more benefits when we write `authenticate` -

```js
function authenticate(uuid, cdcloc)                   // no callback
{ const url = `${cdcloc}/api.php?uuid=${uuid}&auth`
  return getJSON(url)                                 // return promise
    .then(data => {
      if (data.length == 0)
        throw Error("empty response")                 // local error
      else
        return data[0]                                // success
    })                                                // no error-check
}
```

**async/await**

Even Promises have been around for a long time and we've learned a lot since their native inclusion in ECMAScript. Remember to return promises and having to sequence all of the data through `.then` calls is tedious, the same way writing those initial `res.on("data", ...)` and `res.on("end", ...)` handlers felt. `async` and `await` keywords allows us to work with asynchronous control flow without having to sacrifice synchronous programming style -

```js
async function getJSON(url, options = {})   // async
{ const s = await getString(url, options)   // await
  return JSON.parse(s)                      // auto wrapped in Promise
}
```

Writing `authenticate` is easy and feels natural -

```js
async function authenticate(uuid, cdcloc)                 // async 
{ const url = `${cdcloc}/api.php?uuid=${uuid}&auth`
  const data = await getJSON(url)                         // await
  if (data.length == 0)
    throw Error("empty response")                         // throw if empty
  else
    return data[0]                                        // return first
}
```

Using it is easy and feels natural too -

```js
async function connect()
{ const connection = await authenticate( 'DATATOBEPASSED' , 'https://URLHERE')
  console.log(connection.SerialNumber)
  // ...
  return "done"                            // or whatever
}

connect().then(console.log, console.error) // errors bubble all the way up
```

**URL**

I should also mention that building URLs with string concatenation is tedious and prone to a host of errors. You should develop a sense for this pain and know that it means there's room for relief. Take a look at the [URL module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) that can safely build/manipulate URLs in pretty much every way imaginable.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the joys of learning Javascript's asynchronous programming model!

This line

```
const connection = authenticate( 'DATATOBEPASSED' , 'https://URLHERE');
```

returns to its caller before either event handler -- `res.on("data", ...)` and `res.on("data", ...)` get called with the results of your get operation.

You need to use a callback from your `authenticate()` function to deliver the results to its caller.

```js
function authenticate( uuid , cdcloc, callback ) { 
    let url = cdcloc + "/api.php?uuid=" + uuid + '&auth';
    https.get(url,(res) => {
        let body = "";
        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
            try {
                let cdcResponse = JSON.parse(body);
                // do something with JSON
                callback(cdcResponse[0]);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
            };
        });
    }).on("error", (error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
    });
}
authenticate( 'DATATOBEPASSED' , 'https://URLHERE',
    function (connection) {
      console.log(connection.SerialNumber);
    }
 );
```

There are language features known as Promises and async / await to help escape the confusing mess of nested callbacks we get into when we write significant code.

Comment: sure but this goes against node's [error-first callback](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) model