# Promisify a JavaScript callback function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I've been reading everything I can about async/await and Promises, but I can't quite get it to work. I keep getting 'Promise ' and when it's fulfilled I receive 'Undefined'.

I think I've spent about two days on this! I'm not sure what's wrong. Here's the un-promisified version.

```
  const getCoords = (address) => {
    geocoder.addressSearch(address, (result) => {
        return result;
      }
    );
  };
```

And here is my attempt at the promised code:

```
  const getCoords = async (address) => {
     await geocoder.addressSearch(address, async (result) => {
        return result;
  }
);
```

};

I'm just trying to return the result. If anyone could steer me in the right direction it would be really appreciated.

Comment: And what does your promise code look like?

Comment: I just updated the question. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

Both of your examples are incorrect

**using continuation-passing style**

In this style, the continuation ("callback") ignores any `return` values as this function is run asynchronously from the main call -

```js
const geocoder =
  { addressSearch: (address, callback) =>
      setTimeout(callback, 1000, {
        coords: [12.345, 67.890]
      })
  }
  
const getCoords = (address, callback) =>
  geocoder.addressSearch(address, result =>
    callback(result.coords)
  )
  
getCoords("foobar", console.log)
// [ 12.345, 67.89]
```

```js
[ 12.345, 67.89]
```

**using promises**

In this style you do not specify a continuation. Instead a Promise is returned which represents the value of a future computation. You can `await` a promise in an `async` function in order to retrieve the result, or chain a `.then` handler -

```js
const geocoder =
  { addressSearch: (address, callback) =>
      setTimeout(callback, 1000, {
        coords: [12.345, 67.890]
      })
  }
  
const getCoords = (address) =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    geocoder.addressSearch(address, result =>
      resolve(result.coords)
    )
  )
  
async function main() {
  const coords = await getCoords("foobar")
  console.log(coords)
  return "done"
}
  
main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
[ 12.345, 67.89]
"done"
```

Comment: Wow, this is very thorough and excellently written. 

My only problem is that I previously define geocoder like this:

const geocoder = new kakao.maps.services.Geocoder();

So I'm having an issue with the first line of your answer. Do you have a suggestion around it?

Comment: I used a "fake" implementation of `geocoder` in my examples so we can see how they work and they can be tested here on the site in your own browser. If `kakao.maps.services.Geocoder` is written in continuation-passing style, you will write `getCoords` like we did in the first example. If `Geocoder` offers a promise-based API, you will write `getCoords` like we did in the second example.

Comment: Note, if it is written using callback style, it is likely to follow Node's [error-first callback convention](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/). See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33086864/633183) for additional explanation and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873117/633183) for examples how to use with `async` and `await`. If you are stuck after that, please documentation to the link the library you are using and I will try to look into it.