# Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse(<anonymous>) While making a HTTPS GET Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, https, get

I am trying to console the data from "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon" using HTTPS GET request but the console gives the following error:
[Error I am getting while making the GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOPro.png)

This is my code:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu4s1.png)

I make the use of HTTPS Get request method to get the data and was expecting to get the JSON but couldn't.

Comment: `res.on('data',..` gets the response in chunks, you need to capture them all and concatenate, you will get a `res.on('end', ` when all chunks are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`res.on('data')` provides a `stream` of `data`. This means that it sends parts of the request one at a time. When using the https lib you could add the `responses` one by one to a string and then parsing everything in `res.on('end')`. I would suggest though using an easier `HTTP` library, for instance I really like using `axios`. If you cannot figure out how to use `res.on('data'` and `res.on('end'` let me know and I'll type up an example for your situation.

Found the answer here:
[How to get data out of a Node.js http get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539391/how-to-get-data-out-of-a-node-js-http-get-request)

Comment: It's also pretty much in the Docs -> https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Comment: Thank you for answering. An example would help me a lot in figuring out what you are trying to convey.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, it was night for me. Well I think in your case what would work is: 
`https.get(url, res => {
    let result = '';
    res.on('data', data => {
        result += data;
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        const pokemon = JSON.parse(result);
    });
    console.log(pokemon);
});`

Comment: Nice! Could you mark this answer as the correct one, for my rep :-)